# Thunderbirds automatic mail deletion

Tags: server, email, thunderbird, mail

Thunderbird will make me crazy. I am configured with an IMAP mail account, and the server automatically deletes mails after a period of 30 days.
I setted up my account this way :

- right click on my mail address (main display of the application) -> parameters -> synchronization -> **Sychronize all** and **do not delete any message**
- I checked everywhere else, and I configured it **Using my account's parameters**

But I don't understand why I can only see 30days of messages in my main page of Thunderbird.

Comment: Right-click on your inbox folder in the left pane.  Click properties.  On the "Retention Policy" tab, uncheck "Use my account settings" and make sure "Don't delete any messages".  The other option is on the main window under "Tools" -> Account Settings -> Syncronization & Storage (under your account you're using).  On this window, make sure "Don't delete any messages" is checked.

Comment: Could this be a server-side setting? My e-mail provider has a setting like that. I don't remember any such setting in Thunderbird (there's one to purge old messages from the trash folder though and it would be possible to achieve something like that for arbitrary folders via an add-on).

Comment: Thank you, I've done this setting. But I'm wondering, if I configure my account in POP3, can this be solved?